# Search items in treeview in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I tried to do saearchable Treeview the same like someone did in this post to my code: searching in treeview and highlight/select the row that contains the item that is searched. I also wanted to do the way that it doesn't matter to search box when the typed word starts with capital letter or lower letter or the whole word is .upper() or .lower() or .capital(). The problem is, that nothing happens and pops an error about missing one argument when I type the searchable word. The code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

sv = StringVar()
ids = []

def add():
    names = tree.insert("",END,values=(e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get(),e3.get()))
def adds(names):
    for i in range(len(names)):
        ids.append(tree.insert("", "end", text=names[i]))
def command(*args,names):
    selections = [] 
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if entry.get() != "" and entry.get() == names[i][:len(entry.get())]:
            selections.append(ids[i]) 
        tree.selection_set(selections)
sv.trace("w", command)
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sv,width=13) 
entry.grid(row=2,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W) 
e0 = Entry(root,width=15)
e0.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=1,sticky=W)
e1 = Entry(root,width=15)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(root,width=15)
e2.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)
e3 = Entry(root,width=15)
e3.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=4,sticky=W)

btn1 = Button(root,text="add",width=5,command=add)
btn1.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=5)
lb1 = Label(root,text="serial num:")
lb1.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=1)
lb2 = Label(root,text="medicine\nname ")
lb2.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=2)
lb3 = Label(root,text="quatity")
lb3.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=3)
lb4 = Label(root,text="expiry Date")
lb4.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=4)
lb4 = Label(root,text="search box")
lb4.grid(row =1,column=0,rowspan=6)
#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=6,pady=20)
root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You posted your Question 3 times or more. Just speak to the people that already helped you.

Comment: answerd your question here and updated to your needs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676218/sort-the-items-in-treeview/62681563#62681563

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort the items in treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676218/sort-the-items-in-treeview)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to compare the `query` string with the `values` string after casting them to lower case:

Like this:

```
def search():
    query = search_entry.get()
    selections = []
    for child in tree.get_children():
        if query.lower() in tree.item(child)['values'].lower():   # compare strings in  lower cases.
            print(tree.item(child)['values'])
            selections.append(child)
    print('search completed')
    tree.selection_set(selections)
```

Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def add():
    value = add_entry.get()
    values.append(value)
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(f'#{len(values)}', value, 'more', 'moar'))


def search():
    query = search_entry.get()
    selections = []
    for child in tree.get_children():
        if query.lower() in tree.item(child)['values'].lower():   # compare strings in  lower cases.
            print(tree.item(child)['values'])
            selections.append(child)
    print('search completed')
    tree.selection_set(selections)


values = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

lb1 = tk.Label(root, text="Search:")
lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
search_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=15)
search_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E, rowspan=1)
btn = tk.Button(root, text="search", width=10, command=search)
btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=2)

add_lb = tk.Label(root, text="add:")
add_lb.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
add_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=15)
add_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E, rowspan=1)
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="add", width=10, command=add)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=2)

# treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, height=25)
tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
tree.column("one", width=120)
tree.column("two", width=160)
tree.column("three", width=130)
tree.column("four", width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four", text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=6, pady=20)

root.geometry("840x580")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but what if there is child nodes? Is there anyway to iterate through those?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create database

Step 2: Create table

Step 3: Insert values into the database

Step 4: Create tkinter window(slide)

step 5: Create treeview into tkinter window

step 6: Create Search and Reset function

In this code I have defined 3 function:- 1) show()  2) search()  3) reset()

show() will display all data which is present in database.

search() will display search data(given by user) which is present in database.

reset() will call the show()

```
# Step 1 and Step 2:-

# import module
from sqlite3 import *

con = None

# creates/opens database
con = connect("data.db")

# create cursor(connecting user to database)  
cur = con.cursor()

# creates table
sql = "create table student(rno int primary key, name text)"
cur.execute(sql)

# database closed
if con is not None:
    con.close()

# Step 3:-

# import module
from sqlite3 import *

con = None

# create/open database
con = connect("data.db")

# connecting user to database
cur = con.cursor()

# inserting values into database
sql1 = "insert into student values(1, 'darshan')"
sql2 = "insert into student values(2, 'yogesh')"
sql3 = "insert into student values(3, 'devesh')"
sql4 = "insert into student values(4, 'sandip')"
sql5 = "insert into student values(5, 'tushar')"
sql6 = "insert into student values(6, 'raju')"
sql7 = "insert into student values(7, 'rajprasad')"

# executing sql1, sql2, sql3, sql4, sql5, sql6 & sql7
cur.execute(sql1)
cur.execute(sql2)
cur.execute(sql3)
cur.execute(sql4)
cur.execute(sql5)
cur.execute(sql6)
cur.execute(sql7)

# saving inserted data into database
con.commit()

# database closed
if con is not None:
    con.close()

# Step 4, Step 5 and Step 6:-

# Import Modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from sqlite3 import *


view_window = Tk()                       
view_window.title("View Student ")     # title of view_window   
view_window.geometry("750x700+400+50") # set geometry   
view_window.resizable(0, 0)            # disable maximize/minimize view_window      


def show():
    view_window_ent.delete(0, END)     
    view_window_ent.focus()
    tv.selection()
    con = None
    try:
        con = connect("data.db")    
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = "select * from student"   
        cursor.execute(sql)

        fetchdata = tv.get_children()       
        for elements in fetchdata:
            tv.delete(elements)
    

        data = cursor.fetchall()
        for d in data:
            tv.insert("", END, values=d)

        con.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        showerror("Fail", e)
        con.rollback()
    finally:
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
def search():
    tv.selection()
    fetchdata = tv.get_children()
    for f in fetchdata:
        tv.delete(f)
    con = None
    try:
        con = connect("data.db")
        core = con.cursor()
        sql = "select * from student where name = '%s' "
        name = view_window_ent.get()
        if (len(name) < 2) or (not name.isalpha()):
            showerror("fail", "invalid name")
        else:
            core.execute(sql %(name))
            data = core.fetchall()
            for d in data:
                tv.insert("", END, values=d)
            
    except Exception as e:
        showerror("issue", e)

    finally:
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
def reset():
    show()  


#treeview
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(view_window, orient=HORIZONTAL)  
scrollbary = Scrollbar(view_window, orient=VERTICAL)    
tv = ttk.Treeview(view_window, columns=("rollno", "name"), show='headings', height=22)  
tv.pack()
tv.heading('rollno', text="Roll No", anchor=CENTER)
tv.column("rollno", stretch=NO, width = 100) 
tv.heading('name', text="Name", anchor=CENTER)
tv.column("name", stretch=NO)
scrollbary.config(command=tv.yview)
scrollbary.place(x = 526, y = 7)
scrollbarx.config(command=tv.xview)
scrollbarx.place(x = 220, y = 460)
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
style.map("Treeview")


# Widgets
view_window_lbl = Label(view_window, text = "Name", font=('calibri', 12, 'normal'))
view_window_lbl.place(x = 290, y = 518)
view_window_ent = Entry(view_window,  width = 20, font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'))
view_window_ent.place(x = 220, y = 540)
view_window_btn1 = Button(view_window, text = 'Search',  width = 8, font=('calibri', 12, 'normal'), command = search)
view_window_btn1.place(x = 480, y = 540)
view_window_btn2 = Button(view_window, text = 'Reset',  width = 8, font=('calibri', 12, 'normal'), command = reset)
view_window_btn2.place(x = 600, y = 540)


show()  
view_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 to Step 6 :-

Full Example :-

```
# Import Modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from sqlite3 import *


view_window = Tk()                       
view_window.title("View Student ")     # title of view_window   
view_window.geometry("750x700+400+50") # set geometry   
view_window.resizable(0, 0)            # disable maximize/minimize view_window      


# creating table into databse
con = None
# creates/opens database
con = connect("data.db")

# create cursor(connecting user to database)  
cur = con.cursor()

# creates table
sql = "create table student(rno int primary key, name text)"
cur.execute(sql)

# database closed
if con is not None:
    con.close()    


# Inserting data into databse
con = None

# create/open database
con = connect("data.db")

# connecting user to database
cur = con.cursor()

# inserting values into database
sql1 = "insert into student values(1, 'darshan')"
sql2 = "insert into student values(2, 'yogesh')"
sql3 = "insert into student values(3, 'devesh')"
sql4 = "insert into student values(4, 'sandip')"
sql5 = "insert into student values(5, 'tushar')"
sql6 = "insert into student values(6, 'raju')"
sql7 = "insert into student values(7, 'rajprasad')"

# executing sql1, sql2, sql3, sql4, sql5, sql6 & sql7
cur.execute(sql1)
cur.execute(sql2)
cur.execute(sql3)
cur.execute(sql4)
cur.execute(sql5)
cur.execute(sql6)
cur.execute(sql7)

# saving inserted data into database
con.commit()

# database closed
if con is not None:
    con.close()


def show():
    view_window_ent.delete(0, END)     
    view_window_ent.focus()
    tv.selection()
    con = None
    try:
        con = connect("data.db")    
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = "select * from student"   
        cursor.execute(sql)

        fetchdata = tv.get_children()       
        for elements in fetchdata:
            tv.delete(elements)
    

        data = cursor.fetchall()
        for d in data:
            tv.insert("", END, values=d)

        con.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        showerror("Fail", e)
        con.rollback()
    finally:
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
def search():
    tv.selection()
    fetchdata = tv.get_children()
    for f in fetchdata:
        tv.delete(f)
    con = None
    try:
        con = connect("data.db")
        core = con.cursor()
        sql = "select * from student where name = '%s' "
        name = view_window_ent.get()
        if (len(name) < 2) or (not name.isalpha()):
            showerror("fail", "invalid name")
        else:
            core.execute(sql %(name))
            data = core.fetchall()
            for d in data:
                tv.insert("", END, values=d)
            
    except Exception as e:
        showerror("issue", e)

    finally:
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
def reset():
    show()  


#treeview
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(view_window, orient=HORIZONTAL)  
scrollbary = Scrollbar(view_window, orient=VERTICAL)    
tv = ttk.Treeview(view_window, columns=("rollno", "name"), show='headings', height=22)  
tv.pack()
tv.heading('rollno', text="Roll No", anchor=CENTER)
tv.column("rollno", stretch=NO, width = 100) 
tv.heading('name', text="Name", anchor=CENTER)
tv.column("name", stretch=NO)
scrollbary.config(command=tv.yview)
scrollbary.place(x = 526, y = 7)
scrollbarx.config(command=tv.xview)
scrollbarx.place(x = 220, y = 460)
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
style.map("Treeview")


# Widgets
view_window_lbl = Label(view_window, text = "Name", font=('calibri', 12, 'normal'))
view_window_lbl.place(x = 290, y = 518)
view_window_ent = Entry(view_window,  width = 20, font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'))
view_window_ent.place(x = 220, y = 540)
view_window_btn1 = Button(view_window, text = 'Search',  width = 8, font=('calibri', 12, 'normal'), command = search)
view_window_btn1.place(x = 480, y = 540)
view_window_btn2 = Button(view_window, text = 'Reset',  width = 8, font=('calibri', 12, 'normal'), command = reset)
view_window_btn2.place(x = 600, y = 540)


show()  
view_window.mainloop()
```